# How to add long text ffmpeg video

Tags: bash, video, text, ffmpeg, center

I tried adding text in the middle of the video, but the results weren't what I wanted. namely long text out of line, how to make long text automatically into a new line below?

`ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "drawtext=fontfile=/path/to/font.ttf:text='I tried adding text in the middle of the video, but the results are not as desired,':fontcolor=white: fontsize=24:box=1:boxcolor=black@0.5:boxborderw=5:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/2" -codec:a copy output.mp4`

i used that command, and the output like this

[output video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOiBW.png)

Please help

please help my problem

Answer (score 0):

You could try saving the text in a variable via `printf` with the `-v` flag, something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

printf -v long_text "'%b'" "I tried adding text in\nthe middle of the video,\nbut the results are\nnot as desired,"

ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "drawtext=fontfile=/path/to/font.ttf:text=${long_text}:fontcolor=white: fontsize=24:box=1:boxcolor=black@0.5:boxborderw=5:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/2" -codec:a copy output.mp4
```

---

- The `\n` represents a line break or a new line.
- See `help printf`